# Redirect www.sub.domain.com to https://sub.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've tried several rewrite rules trying to make this work, but it would still redirect to `https://www.*`.
What I want to achieve is to redirect, `www.sub.domain.com` to `https://sub.domain.com`.

This is the code I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule doesn't work for two reasons

- `RewriteCond` restricts the rule to requests for sub.domain.net and ignores requests for www.sub.domain.net
- The `RewriteRule` uses `%{HTTP_HOST}` in the substitution. So even if it would apply for www.sub.domain.net, it would just redirect it to www.sub.domain.net again.

So your rule should rather look like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://sub.domain.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).